# Trying to find all of whiskey sales from a certain store -SQL-

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, popsql

I want to find the total sales of Whiskeys at a certain store in the dataset

Here's my code (Using PopSql connected to bigquery)

`SELECT DISTINCT category_name, ROUND(SUM(sale_dollars)) AS Total_Revenue FROM Liquor_Sales.Iowa WHERE store_name = 'HY-VEE #3 / BDI / DES MOINES' AND category_name LIKE '%WHISK%' GROUP BY category_name ORDER BY Total_Revenue DESC;`

This code gives me every category that contains 'Whisk' (I.E. Canadian whiskey, Tennessee whiskey, ETC) and their total sales but I want them to be lumped into one 'Whiskey' category with the Total revenue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you simply remove the category grouping:

```
SELECT
    'Whiskey' AS Category_Name,
    ROUND(SUM(sale_dollars)) AS Total_Revenue
FROM
    Liquor_Sales.Iowa
WHERE
    store_name = 'HY-VEE #3 / BDI / DES MOINES'
    AND 
    category_name LIKE '%WHISK%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am fairly new to SQL and this helps a lot!

Comment: @CalebPool Please consider marking the Accept Answer flag so that others know this question is resolved.